# Find the Jordan canonical form and an invertible $Q$ such that $A=QJQ^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 3 & -2 \\
-7 & 6 & -3 \\
1 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix} $$

The characteristic polynomial can be found to be $p(t)= -(t-1)(t-2)^2$. For

- $t=1$, I have that $K_1 = E_1$. So $\beta_1 = \{ (1,2,1), (-1, -1,1)\}$.
- $t=2$, I have that $K_2 = N(A-2I)^2$. So $\beta_2 = \{ (1, 2,0), (-1, 0, 2), (1,2,1) \} $.

Since $\beta= \beta_1 \cup \beta_2$ I have $\beta=\{ (1,2,1), (1,2,0), (-1,-1,1)\}$. Now I set

$$Q = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 & 1 \\
2 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

But then we have

$$Q^{-1}A Q = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$

This is close to the Jordan canonical form, but not exactly what we want. Could someone please tell me where I did something wrong?

Comment: It will help us (and you probably also) if you define what the $\beta_i$ are.

Comment: $\beta_i$ is the ordered basis for generalized eigenspace $K_{t}$ of $A$ corresponding to $t$. I think I can sort of see what went wrong now. According to one of the theorems (theorem 7.4 in Friedberg's Linear Algebra) we should have $\beta_1\cap \beta_2 = \emptyset$. But I'm sure how I got the repeating vectors here in $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$

Comment: You have incorrectly typed in the matrix $A,$  the one you posted has irrational eigenvalues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your kernels should be 1 and 2 dimensional respectively.

Secondly, you don't want just *any* basis for $\ker(A - 2I)^2$—although you can make this work through some manipulations—rather you want a generator $x$ for $\ker(A - 2I)$ and then some vector $y$ such that $(A - 2I)y = x$. Then $\{x, y\}$ is a basis for $\ker(A - 2I)^2$.

I computed the following:

\begin{align*}
\ker (A - I)  &= \langle (1,2,1) \rangle \\
\ker (A - 2I) &= \langle (1,1,-1) \rangle \\
(A - 2I)y = (1,1,-1) &\iff y \in (1, 2, 0) + \ker (A - 2I)
\end{align*}

I am using $\langle x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots \rangle$ to denote the span.

You see that for the last step, I take a generator for $\ker (A - 2I)$ and then solve $(A - 2I)y = (1,1,-1)$ to get the second generator of $\ker (A - 2I)^2$ (rather than just computing $\ker(A - 2I)^2$ directly).

In total:

$$ Q = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! May I ask what's the difference between computing $\ker (A-2I)^2$ directly and doing it the way you did above?

Comment: @Korn Jordan form asks for subspaces with a basis like $v, (A - \lambda I)v, (A - \lambda I)^2 v, \dots, (A - \lambda I)^{k - 1}v$ and that gives you a Jordan block of size $k$. If you have just any basis for $\ker (A - 2 I)^2$, you then need to modify it to get this special basis.